# The scrollView Resets is position when i scroll down vertically

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

When i try to scroll down the content  , it just resets  his position , i want to 
scrolldown and the position stay where i want , can someone please help me know , what i am missing?

[scrollview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBPJJ.png)

[image: ScrollViewStoryboard]

Comment: Please add the source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using layouts for scrollview. Scrollview will not know its content size unless contentSize or intrinsicSize are setted.

This would result in the bouncy effect which lets user peek into and returns to original position when lifted the finger.

If le is the last element in the scrollview then in your viewDidLoad add

```
scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width,le.frame.size.height+le.frame.orizin.y);
```